# Special Characters not working in link titles

Tags: php, html, css

Basically, i have a site put together with PHP, HTML and CSS. I had a problem with it not showing special characters (eg. å,ä,ö), so i changed the charset from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1. That solved the problem for the text on the site, but everything inside a pair of  tags still fails to show up correctly. Any thoughts?

Edit: I changed back to UTF-8 and Content-Language SV-SE, but now the special characters within  tags output a replacement character instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that’s definitely an encoding issue. as a workaround you can use html encoded chars like `&auml;`. better though to correctly encode your sourcefiles and set the corresponding `<meta>` tag and http headers

Comment: Cheers, i saved the source files with UTF-8 encoding, which solved the issue quite well. Thanks again!